# Ubuntu desktop with bash keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm looking to migrate from OS X to Ubuntu. I'm very used to bash keyboard shortcuts working throughout all applications (ctrl-a=start of like, ctrl-e, ctrl-d etc) as those work in many desktop applications on OS X.

Is there ready-made package/extension/desktop environment, that uses bash keyboard shortcuts throughout, while moving 'linux desktop' shotcuts like ctrl-a=select all to other keys? (Like alt-a?)

(edit: throughout the GUI - i.e. ensuring that bash keyboard shortcuts also work in the GUI)

Comment: What do you mean by "all applications"? Are you including GUI programs such as Firefox, Gedit, LibreOffice, etc?

Comment: those keyboard shortcuts come from linux not from mac that's why they're control not command. command already took most of those combinations for stuff like hiding windows (command + H) so they just put it on the control key like it is on linux. you'll be right at home.

Comment: Check the [list of keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en) from Ubuntu Official Documentation and [the other list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts) from Community Documentation. You also can create your own custom shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you all! Yes, in all GUI apps, so remapping at systems level.

Comment: Yes - they do come from linux - but because of the Apple-command key e.g. ctrl-a has s different meaning in OS X (always start of line, in GUI programmes, shell, everywhere in 'aqua' I believe, which seems to be many). However, in linux ctrl-a is select-all in GUI, but beginning-of-line in shell. So I'd like to have the shell bindings throughout, and then mop up anything missing with other key combinations. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

I've set up this repo https://github.com/bjohas/Ubuntu-keyboard-map-like-OS-X which provides answers to the above! It's not straight forward, but possible.